# Need to write a Ruby method that uses Regex and returns true for strings starting with a capital letter and ending with punctuation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, match

...and returns false for strings starting with a lower case letter and ending with punctuation.

Something like this:

```
def first_word_capitalized_and_ends_with_punctuation?(text)
  !!text.match(/^(A-Z)...$\W/)
end
```

Comment: Nice, but, what is the question?

Comment: It's interesting that your question and all the answers so far use `^` and `$` as anchors. Those are end-of-line anchors, as contrasted with `\A` and `\z`, which are end-of-string anchors. If the string consists of a single line, it makes no difference which anchors are used, but you didn't say the string consists of a single line. If `str = "Now is the\ntime to have fun!"`, the end-of-string anchors must be used...

Comment: ...Some (including me) think the end-of-string anchors should be used whenever the focus is on the string, even if it's a single line. For one, a reader seeing end-of-line markers might pause to see why they may have been used rather than end-of-string markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the regex a bit

```
def first_word_capitalized_and_ends_with_punctuation?(text)
  !!text.match(/^[A-Z].*\W$/)
end
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @spickermann you can also use [**`match?`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F)

```
def first_word_capitalized_and_ends_with_punctuation?(text)
  text.match?(/^[A-Z].*\W$/)
end
```

Comment: Or just `text.match?(/^[A-Z].*\W$/)` when you are on the lastest Ruby version. [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) was added in Ruby 2.4 and is faster than `match`, because it returns a boolean instead of complex match data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression. It matches only capital letters in the beginning of the string, everything in between, and a punctuation character at the end (`\.` `,` `:` or `;`):

```
^[A-Z].*[\.,:;]$
```

And here it is used in your code:

```
def first_word_capitalized_and_ends_with_punctuation?(text)
  !!text.match(/^[A-Z].*[\.,:;]$/)
end
```

*Using `\W` would also match whitespace characters.*